# Allow local-only access on an Istio virtual service

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a Kubernetes Cluster with three servers: 10.15.0.1, 10.15.0.2 and 10.15.0.3. These three IP's are defined as External IP's on the Istio Ingress Gateway.
There is a single external IP that acts as a load balancer to access thoses IPs.
The Istio Ingress Gateway is a LoadBalancer Type and allow access only the ports 80 and 443. I also have an Istio Gateway as follows:

```
- name: Create Istio Ingress Gateway
  community.kubernetes.k8s:
    state: present
    resource_definition:
      - kind: Service
        apiVersion: v1
        metadata:
          name: istio-ingressgateway
          namespace: test
        spec:
          type: LoadBalancer
          selector:
            istio: ingressgateway
          ports:
          - port: 80
            name: http
          - port: 443
            name: https
          externalIPs:
          - 10.15.0.1
          - 10.15.0.2
          - 10.15.0.3
```

```
- name: Create Istio Gateway
  community.kubernetes.k8s:
    state: present
    resource_definition:
      - kind: Gateway
        apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
        metadata:
          name: default-gateway
          namespace: test
        spec:
          selector:
            istio: ingressgateway
          servers:
          - port:
              number: 80
              name: http
              protocol: HTTP
            hosts:
            - "*"
            tls:
              httpsRedirect: true
          - port:
              number: 443
           ...
```

```
- name: Create Istio Ingress Deployment
  community.kubernetes.k8s:
    state: present
    resource_definition:
      - kind: Deployment
        apiVersion: apps/v1
        metadata:
          name: istio-ingressgateway
          namespace: test
        spec:
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              istio: ingressgateway
          template:
            metadata:
              annotations:
                # Select the gateway injection template (rather than the default sidecar template)
                inject.istio.io/templates: gateway
              labels:
                # Set a unique label for the gateway. This is required to ensure Gateways can select this workload
                istio: ingressgateway
                # Enable gateway injection. If connecting to a revisioned control plane, replace with "istio.io/rev: revision-name"
                sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
            spec:
              containers:
              - name: istio-proxy
                image: auto # The image will automatically update each time the pod starts.
```

For every service that I want to access using an FQDN, I create a virtual service as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: testapi
  namespace: test
spec:
  hosts:
  - testapi.test.test
  gateways:
  - default-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: test
```

So, on my DNS, I simply insert testapi.test.test as an A record with the external IP address. Everything works well, but there are services that I would like to access using an FQDN but only accessible from my local network, like Portainer.
If I access portainer.test.test from an external network, it should not be accessible. But if I access portainer.test.test from my local network, it should be accessible. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: How did you set up your cluster and which versions of Kubernetes and Istio did you use? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I set up using the tool kubeadm with default settings, there are two master nodes. The versions are: kubernetes 1.22.1 and istio 1.11.1. The problem can be resumed as: I need to run two separated ingress gateway, a local network only and one available externaly. I have two load balance IP's, one external and one internal. The reason is to have an monitoring like grafana.my.domain that is available only local and an API api.my.domain that is available externaly.

Comment: So, could you please specify how specifically (step by step) you want your network traffic to go?